# I want to parse data from JSON to PHP, but for the array "link" with the URN, the system will not take the data

Tags: php, html

For now some of the "Read More" appear to some article but not on the article that i desire. I need the article from "Yankees' Rivera earns 600th career save (AP)" and "Toyota taking orders in Japan for Prius Plug-in" only show "Read More" since its the only article without "urn:....". i already tried to remove "!" in "preg_match", it seem to be worked, but in vice versa.[image]

This is my JSON data, if the article have for example "urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,ap:20050301:mlb,article,ap-310913102.torbos.recap:1", i dont want the coding take the URL.

```css
[
   {
      "title": "Yankees' Rivera earns 600th career save (AP)",

"link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/sports/rss/top/SIG=11jrnp014/*http%3A//sports.yahoo.com/mlb/recap?gid=310913112",
   },
   {
      "title": "Bowden: I had prostate cancer in 2007 (AP)",
      "link": [
         "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/sports/rss/top/SIG=11sb0oir9/*http%3A//sports.yahoo.com/ncaaf/news?slug=ap-bowden-cancer",
         "urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,ap:20050301:ncaaf,article,ap-bowden-cancer:1"
      ],
   {
      "title": "Wakefield finally gets 200th win in rout (AP)",
      "link": [
         "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/sports/rss/top/SIG=11jp8126r/*http%3A//sports.yahoo.com/mlb/recap?gid=310913102",
         "urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,ap:20050301:mlb,article,ap-310913102.torbos.recap:1"
      ],
   {
      "title": "NCAA gives Boise State 3 years probation (AP)",
      "link": [
         "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/sports/rss/top/SIG=125l6dk7s/*http%3A//sports.yahoo.com/ncaaf/news?slug=ap-boisest-ncaaviolations",
         "urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,ap:20050301:ncaaf,article,ap-boisest-ncaaviolations:1"
      ],
   {
      "title": "Toyota taking orders in Japan for Prius Plug-in",
      "link": [
         "http://news.yahoo.com/toyota-taking-orders-japan-prius-plug-041520935.html"
      ],
      
   {
      "title": "Steelers place starting RT Colon on IR (AP)",
      "link": [
         "urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,ap:20050301:nfl,article,ap-steelers-colon:1"
      ],
```

```html
<html>

   <body>
      
      <?php
        $jsondata = file_get_contents("data.json");
        $json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
        $output = "<ul>";
        usort($json,function($a,$b) {return strnatcasecmp($a['title'],$b['title']);});
        
        foreach($json as $new){
            $output .= "<h2>".$new["title"]."</h2>";
            foreach ($new['link'] as $url) {
                if (preg_match('/^urn:/', $url)) {
                    $output .= "<a href=".$url.">Read More</a>";
                    break;
                }
            }
            $output .= "<p>".$new["description"]."</p>";
            $output .= date('<\i>l</\i> <\i>jS</\i> <\i>\of</\i> <\i>F</\i> <\i>Y</\i> <\i>h</\i>:<\i>i</\i>:<\i>s</\i> <\i>A</\i>',strtotime($new["pubDate"]));
        }
        $output .= "</ul>";
        echo $output;
        
        
      ?>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested loop through `$new['link']` and only add the item without `urn:`.

```
        foreach($json as $new){
            $output .= "<h2>".$new["title"]."</h2>";
            foreach ($new['link'] as $url) {
                if (!preg_match('/^urn:/', $url)) {
                    $output .= "<a href=".$url.">Read More</a>";
                    break;
                }
            }
            $output .= "<p>".$new["description"]."</p>";
            $output .= date('<\i>l</\i> <\i>jS</\i> <\i>\of</\i> <\i>F</\i> <\i>Y</\i> <\i>h</\i>:<\i>i</\i>:<\i>s</\i> <\i>A</\i>',strtotime($new["pubDate"]));
        }
```

Comment: It effect some of the link, but is does not do what i required. To be in detail, i need the url for "Yankees' Rivera earns 600th career save (AP)" and "Toyota taking orders in Japan for Prius Plug-in" only show the "Read More" since these two article does not exist "urn:" in the "link" description

and there is this error:
"Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in I:\XAMPP\htdocs\OskyWeb\News.php on line 13"

Comment: Can you update the question and show what the desired result is?

Comment: okay,  its updated

Comment: I meant the desired HTML.

Comment: there is no desired HTML, there is just JSON code that needs to be parsed into PHP with a condition where I only need to take the "link" that is no "urn:" attached in the text

example:
{
      "title": "Wakefield finally gets 200th win in rout (AP)",
      "link": [
         "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/sports/rss/top/SIG=11jp8126r/*http%3A//sports.yahoo.com/mlb/recap?gid=310913102",
         "urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,ap:20050301:mlb,article,ap-310913102.torbos.recap:1"
      ],

I didn' have to take this link since it has "urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,ap:...."

Comment: Of course there's desired HTML. It's the HTML that's being put into the `$output` variable.

Comment: did you mean the JSON code? I only use 2 files. News.php and data.json. and both I have already shown above.

Comment: No, I mean all the `<h2>` and `<a>` elements that are being created in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: act i didnt quite understand, but i already re-edit my JSON code. basically I use   $jsondata = file_get_contents("data.json"); to fetch data from JSON file. so all the data are from JSON

Comment: I don't care where the JSON is coming from. You said I'm not producing the correct results, I don't understand what the correct results should be. Your description in English isn't clear, so I want you to show me the results in HTML.